# Cocos2D Low Audio Volume in iPhone 3G?

Tags: audio, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, avaudiorecorder, iphone-3gs

I have a Cocos2D(Box2D) project that contains AVAudioRecorder object (Microphone Listening). I've not problem with audio in iPhone 4, but the audio volume in iPhone 3G is very low! I did increase device volume to the max volume but the audio volume still not changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem! The audio volume is low cause audio played in phone call speaker (not main speaker).

To play audio in main speaker we need this code:

```
UInt32 doChangeDefaultRoute = 1;     
AudioSessionSetProperty(
   kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker,
   sizeof(doChangeDefaultRoute),
   &doChangeDefaultRoute
);
```

Comment: @Vikalp: What grammar was corrected? And we don't need the bold.